# Update Elasticsearch's mappings of an existing index

Tags: java, elasticsearch, spring-data-elasticsearch

I have an existing index "my-index" in Elastic. I'm trying to update this existing index with new fields without losing data.

I also tried to update the existing index with .putMapping function of RestHighLevelClient but I still got an error like this

> Elasticsearch exception [type=mapper_parsing_exception, reason=Failed to parse mapping [_doc]: Root mapping definition has unsupported parameters:...

Here are the mappings of my existing index

```
{
  "mappings": {
    "_doc": {
      "properties": {
        "_class": {
          "type": "text",
          "fields": {
            "keyword": {
              "type": "keyword",
              "ignore_above": 420
            }
          }
        },
        "taskType": {
          "type": "integer"
        },
        "updateTime": {
          "type": "date",
          "format": "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss"
        },
        "workType": {
          "type": "integer"
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

And my expected index is

```
{
  "mappings": {
    "_doc": {  
    "mappings": {
    "dynamic_templates": [
      {
        "strings": {
          "match_mapping_type": "string",
          "mapping": {
            "type": "keyword"
          }
        }
      },
      {
        "dates": {
          "match_mapping_type": "date",
          "mapping": {
            "type": "date",
            "format": "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss"
          }
        }
      }
    ],
      "properties": {
        "_class": {
          "type": "text",
          "fields": {
            "keyword": {
              "type": "keyword",
              "ignore_above": 420
            }
          }
        },
        "date": {
          "type": "long"
        },
        "favorite_color": {
          "type": "keyword"
        },
        "is_active": {
          "type": "boolean"
        },
        "number_float": {
          "type": "float"
        },
        "number_long": {
          "type": "long"
        },
        "taskType": {
          "type": "integer"
        },
        "updateTime": {
          "type": "date",
          "format": "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss"
        },
        "updatedDate": {
          "type": "date",
          "format": "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss"
        },
        "workType": {
          "type": "integer"
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Can I update the existing index without losing any data using spring-data-elasticsearch repository??? Thanks for helping.

Comment: which version of Spring Data Elasticsearch do you use? The `RestHighLevel` client is deprectaed anyway.

Comment: I am using Spring Data Elasticsearch with 4.0.8 version

Comment: well that's pretty outdated; 4.0.8 was release on March 17, 2021, the 4.0 branch had EOL in February 2022.

Answer (score 1):

To update your existing index mapping without losing data, you can use one of these methods:

1. Use the reindex API to create a new index with the new mapping and copy the data from the old index to the new index. Then change the alias to point to the new index. This method preserves your data and allows you to change any mapping parameter, but it requires extra disk space and time for reindexing.
2. Use the update mapping API to add new fields or change some supported mapping parameters of existing fields in your old index. This method does not require reindexing or extra disk space, but it has some limitations on what you can change. For example, you cannot change the field type or analyzer of an existing field.
3. Use spring-data-elasticsearch repository to perform either of the above methods using Java code. You can use @Mapping annotation on your entity class to specify the mapping for your new index, and use ElasticsearchOperations.reindex() method to reindex your data from old index to new index. You can also use ElasticsearchOperations.putMapping() method to update your existing index mapping with some supported changes.

Answer (score 0):

You can't change a field type, and you can't remove any existing fields but you can add additional fields to your existing mapping.
Here is the official documentation about it. [ESv6](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/6.6/indices-put-mapping.html) and [ESv8](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/indices-put-mapping.html)

Here is an example:

Create the index

```
PUT my_index 
{
  "mappings": {
    "_doc": {
      "properties": {
        "name": {
          "properties": {
            "first": {
              "type": "text"
            }
          }
        },
        "user_id": {
          "type": "keyword"
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Update the mapping

```
PUT my_index/_mapping/_doc
{
  "properties": {
    "name": {
      "properties": {
        "last": { 
          "type": "text"
        }
      }
    },
    "user_id": {
      "type": "keyword",
      "ignore_above": 100 
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: If I want to insert the "dynamic fields" block that is outside the "properties" block. Any solution for this bro?

Comment: Can you clarify your question? I didn't understood :/

Comment: oh sorry guy! I just edited/updated my expected index above. You might scroll up to see what I mentioned.

Answer (score 0):

can't change a field type, and you can't remove any existing fields